# I am currently learning to make a discord bot. I want to create a switch statement

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import os
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('we have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user: 
    return

  if message.content.startswith('$Hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello! write "$Help" to find more about the Noriku bot ')
  
  if message.content.startswith('$Help'):
    await message.channel.send('Hi again! The noriku bot is still in beta stages...the only 2 commands are $Hello and $Help')
  

client.run(os.getenv('token'))
```

What I am trying to do is to make switch statement since many professionals say that is better than making if statements

Comment: Does https://wiki.python.org/moin/SwitchStatement help?

Answer (score 1):

Python has no switch-case statement. Regardless, it is not necessary in your case as your code is already readable, and switch-case would not apply since you are using a function (`.startswith()`). Switch-case statements are only "better" in specific cases. Given that you are only checking for 2 conditions, that approach is already the best.

However, if you were to increase the number of conditions, you should then refactor it by placing your strings in a data structure such as a dictionary, so that you do not keep repeating your code.

```py
commands = {
    '$Hello' : 'Hello! write "$Help" to find more about the Noriku bot ',
    '$Help' : 'Hi again! The noriku bot is still in beta stages...the only 5 commands are $Hello, $Help, $Test1, $Test2, and $Test3',
    '$Test1' : 'This is Test1',
    '$Test2' : 'This is Test2',
    '$Test3' : 'This is Test3'
}

...

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user: 
        return

    for key, value in commands.items():
        if message.content.startswith(key):
            await message.channel.send(value)
```

This way, you do not have make additional if statements for every command you make.

Once you're a little comfortable with these, you may want to check out [Commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html).

Comment: Just to add to this structural pattern matching (basically switch) has been introduced in version 3.10. https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching

Comment: Oh, a new feature! Thanks for the information. To the OP, I still don't think match-case will be applicable to your use case.